# Ada 95 - while-loop inside Subprogram gives output ***inf***

Tags: ada

**Desciption:** The program I'm making in Ada 95 is suppose to output a Tax-list depending on input from the user like below:

Price without taxes | Tax | Price with taxes

If the user input **First Price: 10**, **Last Pris:** 20, **Steps:** 0.5 and **Tax** as a Integer. The program then iterates from 10 to 20 with steps of 0.5 before stopping.

The issue I'm facing is the output of the value of " Tax " and " Price with taxes ". The result I'm getting is ****inf**** on both columns. I have no idea what this actually means, and I cant't find any other information on this. So I made another attempt and got the result I wanted except the first line inside the iteration. It started with the Value 10 Taxes = 0 and last Pris with taxes = 0, but all other columns and lines were correct.

Is it not suppose to work the same way with subprograms the way it does with loops as in the Main? I have the exact same program in another file, the difference is it is all in the Main and not inside a Subprogram as this.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to solve it?

-------- Code ------------------------------------------------------

```
with Ada.Text_IO;          use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;  use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;  
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;    use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Momstabell is

-- First Price, Last Price, Steps & Taxes(in Integer),- Subprogram

procedure Hamta(S : in String;
        Tal : out Float ) is

begin


    Put(S);
    loop
        Get(Tal); 
        exit when Tal > 0.0;
    end loop;


 end Hamta;
```

---

```
procedure Skriv_Ut(Forsta_Pris, Sista_Pris, Steg, Momsprocent : in 
Float) is

  First_Price, Last_Price, Steps, Price_With_Tax, Tax_Percentage, Tax : 
  Float;

begin

    New_Line;
    Put("=== Price List ===");New_Line;
    Put("Price without tax ");
    Put("Tax ");
    Put("Price with tax");

    -- Local Variables --
    First_Price := Forsta_Pris;
    Last_Price := Sista_Pris;
    Steps := Steg;
    Tax_Percentage := Momsprocent;

    Tax := Tax_percentage/First_Price;
    Price_With_Tax := First_Price + Tax;

  while First_Price <= Last_Price loop

      New_Line;
      Put("    ");
      Put(First_Price, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      Put("     ");
      Put(Tax, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      Put("     ");
      Put(Price_With_Tax, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);

 -- Iteration --

      First_Price := First_Price + Steps;
      Tax := First_Price / Tax_Percentage;
      Price_With_Tax := First_Price + Tax;


  end loop;

end Skriv_Ut;
```

---

```
-- Deklaration of Variables

Forsta_Pris: Float;
Sista_Pris: Float;
Steg: Float;
Momsprocent: Float;
Moms : Float;

begin

    Hamta("Mata in första pris: ",Forsta_Pris);
    Hamta("Mata in sista pris: ", Sista_Pris);
    Hamta("Mata in Steg: ",Steg);
    Hamta("Mata in Momsprocent: ",Moms);
    Skriv_Ut(Forsta_Pris, Sista_Pris, Steg, Momsprocent);

end Momstabell;
```

---

Best regards
Robert

Comment: Snapshot of the code would be very useful to get reasonable answers.

Comment: Copy/paste preferable to snapshot. Codepen / JsFiddle preferable to copy/paste :)

Comment: Your question is about Ada, so copy/paste. No Javascript, so no JsFiddle, and probably no Codepen either.

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't completely sure if that was tolerated. The main focus lies on the " procedure Skriv_Ut(Forsta_Pris, Sista_Pris, Steg, Momsprocent : in Float) is ", thats where the " Skriv ut = Output " is.

Answer (score 2):

When I compile your code (with `-gnatl` to get compiler messages interleaved with a code listing), I get

```
70. Steg: Float;
71. Momsprocent: Float;
    |
    >>> warning: variable "Momsprocent" is read but never assigned

72. Moms : Float;
```

To avoid wheeling out the debugger, I changed the declarations in `Skriv_Ut` to

```
subtype My_Float is Float range Float'Range;
First_Price, Last_Price, Steps, Price_With_Tax, Tax_Percentage, Tax :
  My_Float;
```

because GNAT doesn’t detect floating-point numeric overflow - this code will detect Inf (and probably NaN) results.

Running the program gives

```
$ ./momstabell
Mata in första pris: 10
Mata in sista pris: 20
Mata in Steg: .5
Mata in Momsprocent: 5

=== Price List ===
Price without tax Tax Price with tax
    10.00      0.00     10.00

raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : englund.ada:59 range check failed
```

where line 59 is

```
58.       First_Price := First_Price + Steps;
59.       Tax := First_Price / Tax_Percentage;
60.       Price_With_Tax := First_Price + Tax;
```

---

I think your problem is these two lines:

```
Hamta("Mata in Momsprocent: ",Moms);
Skriv_Ut(Forsta_Pris, Sista_Pris, Steg, Momsprocent);
```

Comment: Thank you alot Simon Wright, you just made my day! I've been bashing my head trying to find the problem for 2 days and never chest:

    Hamta("Mata in Momsprocent: ",Moms);
    Skriv_Ut(Forsta_Pris, Sista_Pris, Steg, Momsprocent);

The first line of code " Moms " which means Tax, doesn't match the second row with " Momspercent " which is the percentage. I always thought it had to do with the math inside the while-loop.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting float Infinity in regular calculations, you're most probably dividing by zero.

Also, you mustn't use floats for money if you need the resulting sums to match to a penny.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for the fast comment! The real issue for me is that the while-loop works in the previous program I wrote, with the exact same variables including the iteration.

Now when I'm trying to use Subprograms it doesn't work, and I'm getting the float infinity.

Comment: @R.Englund did you try to, well, debug the program? It looks okay algorithm-wise at first glance, so the problem is probably in some implementation detail.